Many wired connection duplicates in Kubuntu 24.04 tray Network Manager
After upgrading from Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04 LTS, I've got a lot of connection duplicates in the tray Network Manager:

Additionally, every few minutes I am facing disconnection and re-connection. My network programs are VPN and Docker.
The "clones" are actually Virtual Ethernet Devices and do not appear in System Settings → Connections:

They are not in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections so I can't delete them:
# ll /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections 
итого 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 авг  2 09:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 авг  5 11:16 ../
# cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

I tried using nmcli connection show to get their UUID and nmcli connection delete (by UUID) to delete them, but after rebooting they appeared again with another UUID.
How can I remove these duplicate connections from the tray Network Manager?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Did you find something related on sudo journalctl -xe?

Since you get a lot of Virtual Connections and they cause connection drops, it indicates that one of your network programs is not working correctly. It's most likely Docker, since you mentioned that you use it.
So try to reinstall Docker following the official instructions. As mentioned in the Prerequisites section:

Note
The latest Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is not yet supported. Docker Desktop will fail to start. Due to a change in how the latest Ubuntu release restricts the unprivileged namespaces, sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 needs to be run at least once.

Additionally, since  Kubuntu uses KDE Plasma Desktop instead of GNOME, you must also install GNOME Terminal before installing Docker:


For non-Gnome Desktop environments, gnome-terminal must be installed:
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal




Then follow the procedure in the Install Docker Desktop section, which I'm quoting below:

Recommended approach to install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu:

Set up Docker's package repository. See step one of Install using the apt repository.

Download latest DEB package.

Install the package with apt as follows:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<arch>.deb


Note
At the end of the installation process, apt displays an error due to installing a downloaded package. You can ignore this error message.
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file '/home/user/Downloads/docker-desktop.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)




There are a few post-install configuration steps done through the post-install script contained in the deb package.
The post-install script:

Sets the capability on the Docker Desktop binary to map privileged ports and set resource limits.
Adds a DNS name for Kubernetes to /etc/hosts.
Creates a symlink from /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli to /usr/bin/docker. This is because the classic Docker CLI is installed at /usr/bin/docker. The Docker Desktop installer also installs a Docker CLI binary that includes cloud-integration capabilities and is essentially a wrapper for the Compose CLI, at /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli. The symlink ensures that the wrapper can access the classic Docker CLI.



A lot of troubleshooting was carried out in chat. The discussion is here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154476/discussion-between-amar-and-arkhamvm


Boot with the recovery mood to delete all connection information:
rm -rf /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
rm -rf /var/lib/NetworkManager/*


Reboot with the normal state and reconfigure the connection.



It doesn't change anything :(
